# cSplit Coerces Unnecessary NA Row

Tags: r, string, delimiter, splitstackshape, csplit

I have a large data set a small sample of which looks like the 4 x 5 tibble below. I'm trying to split multiple delimited columns into unique rows using variable `c=="Split"` as below:

```
library(splitstackshape)

dt <- tibble(
a = c("Quartz | White Spirit | Wildfire", "Quiet Riot", "Race Against Time", "Down | Heart Lane | X | Breaking H"),
b = c("Muthas Pride", "Killer Girls / Slick Black Cadillac", "Demo 1980", "Life 55"),
c = c("Split", "Single", "Demo", "Split"),
d = c("Birmingham, England | Hartlepool, England | Sheffield, South Yorkshire, England", "Los Angeles, California", "Nottingham, England", "Liverpool | Beijing | | NYC"),
e = c("wf | ef | ff", "g", "f", "cf | af | df | rf")
)

dt.s <- subset(dt, c == "Split")
dt.split <- cSplit(dt.s, c("a", "d", "e"), c("|", "|", "|"), "long") 
dt.split
```

However, this coerces an extra row of NAs as seen in row 4:

```
             a            b     c                                   d  e
1:       Quartz Muthas Pride Split                 Birmingham, England wf
2: White Spirit Muthas Pride Split                 Hartlepool, England ef
3:     Wildfire Muthas Pride Split Sheffield, South Yorkshire, England ff
4:           NA Muthas Pride Split                                  NA NA
5:         Down      Life 55 Split                           Liverpool cf
6:   Heart Lane      Life 55 Split                             Beijing af
7:            X      Life 55 Split                                     df
8:   Breaking H      Life 55 Split                                 NYC rf
```

This is not a problem if I split only two columns. How do I get it to not produce the NA row? And, is there a way to make `cSplit` work without subsetting by `c`?

Answer (score 0):

As we are using a `tibble`, we could use the `separate_rows`, which is not giving the `NA` rows

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(dt.s, c('a', "d", "e"), sep="\\s*\\|\\s*") %>%
         select_at(names(dt.s))
# A tibble: 7 x 5
#             a            b     c                                   d     e
#         <chr>        <chr> <chr>                               <chr> <chr>
#1       Quartz Muthas Pride Split                 Birmingham, England    wf
#2 White Spirit Muthas Pride Split                 Hartlepool, England    ef
#3     Wildfire Muthas Pride Split Sheffield, South Yorkshire, England    ff
#4         Down      Life 55 Split                           Liverpool    cf
#5   Heart Lane      Life 55 Split                             Beijing    af
#6            X      Life 55 Split                                        df
#7   Breaking H      Life 55 Split                                 NYC    rf
```

---

Regarding why the `cSplit` is giving an extra row of NA, it would be better to check the output in the 'wide' format

```
cSplit(dt.s, c("a", "d", "e"), "|")
#              b     c    a_1          a_2      a_3        a_4                 d_1                 d_2                                 d_3 d_4 e_1 e_2 e_3 e_4
#1: Muthas Pride Split Quartz White Spirit Wildfire         NA Birmingham, England Hartlepool, England Sheffield, South Yorkshire, England  NA  wf  ef  ff  NA
#2:      Life 55 Split   Down   Heart Lane        X Breaking H           Liverpool             Beijing                                     NYC  cf  af  df  rf
```

Here, we find that for the second row, the number of delimiter i.e. `|` is 4 creating a `NA` for the first row as there are only 3 delimiters for the 'a column.  So, when we use the 'long' format, this `NA` row propagates.  It could be a bug.

Comment: Thanks but running the above code on the data set (not example from above) gives the following error: `Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.`

Comment: @1984 Sorry to hear that.  I only tested on your example data

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `makeEqual = FALSE` to your `cSplit` call:

```
cSplit(dt.s, c("a", "d", "e"), "|", "long", makeEqual = FALSE)
##               a            b     c                                   d  e
## 1:       Quartz Muthas Pride Split                 Birmingham, England wf
## 2: White Spirit Muthas Pride Split                 Hartlepool, England ef
## 3:     Wildfire Muthas Pride Split Sheffield, South Yorkshire, England ff
## 4:         Down      Life 55 Split                           Liverpool cf
## 5:   Heart Lane      Life 55 Split                             Beijing af
## 6:            X      Life 55 Split                                     df
## 7:   Breaking H      Life 55 Split                                 NYC rf
```

Also, since you're already using packages from the "tidyverse", you can subset along with splitting, like this:

```
dt %>% 
  filter(c == "Split") %>% 
  cSplit(c("a", "d", "e"), "|", "long", makeEqual = FALSE)
```